# Z3 takes an unexpected amount of time for an XOR cipher

Tags: python, z3, smt

I'm attempting to learn Z3 by break a simple (3 character) XOR-cipher: https://projecteuler.net/problem=59

So far I've specified some simple requirements, like the plaintext needing to be equivalent to the ciphertext ^ password, that the plaintext must consist of 7 bit ascii and that the password uses only lowercase characters.

```
ciphertext_bytes = parse_input("p059_cipher.txt")
set_param("parallel.enable", True)
set_param("parallel.threads.max", os.cpu_count())
s = Solver()
ctx = s.ctx

password = IntVector('x', 3, ctx)
ciphertext = IntVector('c', len(ciphertext_bytes), ctx)
plaintext = IntVector('p', len(ciphertext_bytes), ctx)

for x in password:
    s.add(x >= 97)
    s.add(x <= 122)

for i, value in enumerate(ciphertext_bytes):
    ciphertext[i] = Int(value, ctx)
    password_index = i % len(password)

    password_char = BitVecRef(Z3_mk_int2bv(ctx.ref(), 8, password[password_index].as_ast()), ctx)
    ciphertext_char = BitVecRef(Z3_mk_int2bv(ctx.ref(), 8, ciphertext[i].as_ast()), ctx)
    plaintext_char = BitVecRef(Z3_mk_int2bv(ctx.ref(), 8, plaintext[i].as_ast()), ctx)

    s.add(password_char ^ ciphertext_char == plaintext_char)

    s.add(plaintext[i] >= 0)
    s.add(plaintext[i] <= 127)
    s.add(ciphertext[i] >= 0)
    s.add(ciphertext[i] <= 255)

print(s.check())
print(s.model())
```

The `s.check()` call does not terminate in any reasonable amount of time however.

As the specified problem is (currently still) brute-forceable with 26*3 tries (guessing each of the password chars separately and checking the plaintext after) I must have made a mistake somewhere.

Why is this code slow?

Why does Z3 not use multi-threading here?

Comment: See if you can cast everything in terms of bit vectors to start with and avoid the `Int` completely. Conversions through `int2bv` can be expensive. I trust that should fix the issue.

Comment: Allright. I'll give pure bitvectors a try. Does Z3 support two dimensional arrays/bitvectors?

Comment: It sure does. But you're probably better of doing arrays/lists directly in Python, and filling it with symbolic elements. That'll be more performant in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really a suitable problem for an SMT solver, alas. The issue here is *not* that you can't solve the puzzle using SMT; but rather it does not buy you anything new. Note that in an XOR based encryption, the equality:

```
  cipher = plain ^ key
```

has a solution for *every* value of `cipher` and `key`: You simply get a plain-text as a sequence of bytes, and the SMT solver has no way of making sure that it's valid English. (Yes, you can constrain it to be 7-bits per character etc., but that's really not cutting down the search space in any meaningful way.) The trick here is to make sure the plain text is "meaningful" English, as is the password. But there's no inherent knowledge in the SMT solver to tell you if a sequence of bytes correspond to meaningful English text, or text in any known natural language.

The best way to solve this problem, then, is to use classic decipher technology; like frequency analysis, dictionary based enumeration, etc. And none of that is really going to gain anything from an SMT solver.
Alternatively, given this is an Euler-project problem, your best best is probably to scan through the dictionary file in your computer and exhaustively search for a suitable solution; since there're only so many 3-letter words that can be used as valid passwords.

Regarding the "speed" issue you're observing: Note that `int2bv` is an expensive operation. You should avoid it, and simply use bit-vectors. But again, this will not help you here, because you'll "quickly" get a non-sense solution.

Comment: I should add that I planned to specify further constraints (like specific words occuring at least once in the text) after testing. The original Project Euler question is of course easily solved in conventional python. It's just something that *should* in theory be solvable with an SMT solver and I'm trying to get familiar with them anyway, so more of a "good learning opportunity". Arrays in Z3 seem to support some kind of "relative" indexing, so specifying constraints like "this word should appear at least once, anywhere" might work.

Comment: Sure.. If you want to learn about z3 programming, however, I'd recommend starting with other problems where SMT solvers are much better at. I think this problem is just not the best application of the technology. There are many problems/solutions listed in https://sat-smt.codes/SAT_SMT_by_example.pdf for instance.